# Derivative of path along a function's root in terms of its Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am working with a function of two variables $F(x,y)$ whose solutions form a continuous path through its domain. This path may be parameterised by a variable $t$:

$F(X(t),Y(t)) = 0$

F(x,y) is a complicated function which I evaluate by performing a numerical integration, however once this is done its derivatives are related by a recursion relation and so may easily be calculated.

I'm able to solve $F(x,y) = 0$ with a minimisation algorithm to find $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ and in theory this means that the derivatives $X'=\frac{dX}{dt}$ and $Y'=\frac{dY}{dt}$ can then be obtained by numerically differentiating.

However, the answers I get are subject to large numerical error and I feel as if this final step is unnecessary; there must be some way to calculate $X'$ and $Y'$ using the derivatives of F and the values of X and Y but I can't figure out what this is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Chain Rule,

$$\frac{d}{dt} F(x(t), y(t)) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{d y }{dt} =0.$$

This gives a linear system (the best that can be found in general). However, if suitable partials are known to exist and be non-zero, we can use the Implicit Function Theorem. For example, if $y=y(x)$, then

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-\partial F / \partial x}{\partial F / \partial y}.$$

Comment: Thinking about my question more carefully I've realised that I didn't describe it correctly. However, I think your answer is the correct one to the question I asked! Additionally mentioning the implicit function theorem helped me find the solution I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible to use automatic differentiation? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation

You can create a type which performs the differentiation at the same time as your minimization algorithm.

This should really be a comment - but I lack sufficient rep:-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - looks like a very powerful technique! I'm not sure it would be much help in this case but certainly something I'll consider using for other problems.

Comment: It's a very powerful technique - I hope it helps someday :-)